# Is the following a fair betting game?

Tags: probability

There is [this](http://www.braingle.com/brainteasers/teaser.php?op=2&id=26344&comm=0) problem I found.

The answer to this brain teaser is different to mine because they used a bit different approach, which changes the solution completely.

I was thinking in terms of a single person playing against the dealer. If that were the case then the set of realizations would be:

$$\Omega_X = \{ 1,1,1, 2,2,2,3,3,3,...,6,6,6\}$$

Then $P[\text{one die is my number}] = 3/18=1/6$

Since the tosses are independent, then $P[\text{two of my numbers show up}] = 1/6 \cdot 1/6 = 1/36$, hence $P[\text{three show up}]=1/6^3$. We are also interested in the complement to the union of these events: $P[(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3)^c] = 1-1/6-1/36-1/216 \approx 80\%$

The game is deemed to be fair if the expected winnings/losses are zero.

Since we know that:

$\mathbb{E}[\cdot] = \sum p_{\omega}X(\omega)$

Then $\mathbb{E}[\text{winnigs}] = 1/6 \cdot (\$1) + 1/36 \cdot (\$3) + 1/216 \cdot (\$5) - (1-1/6-1/36-1/216) \approx -\$0.53$

Thu, unfair (for when one player plays against the dealer). This is correct, right?

Comment: No it is not correct. E.g. the probability that  your number shows up exactly $2$ times is $\frac16\frac16\frac56+\frac16\frac56\frac16+\frac56\frac16\frac16$.

Comment: ahh... I felt like that was wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ denotes the number of dice showing the chosen face then $X$ takes values in $\{0,1,2,3\}$ with:

- $P(X=0)=\frac56\frac56\frac56=\frac{125}{216}$
- $P(X=1)=\frac16\frac56\frac56+\frac56\frac16\frac56+\frac56\frac56\frac16=\frac{75}{216}$
- $P(X=2)=\frac16\frac16\frac56+\frac16\frac56\frac16+\frac56\frac16\frac16=\frac{15}{216}$
- $P(X=3)=\frac16\frac16\frac16=\frac1{216}$

For the expected winning we find:$$(-1)\times\frac{125}{216}+1\times\frac{75}{216}+3\times\frac{15}{216}+5\times\frac1{216}=0$$